# Movable Type 4 vs 5

Tags: upgrade, movabletype

I have a Movable Type site running MT 4.38, and I was wondering whether I should upgrade to 5.

For a while, MT 4 and 5 seemed to have been developed concurrently, but now I only see activity in MT 5. Has MT 4 been abandoned?

The person using the site is change averse, so I only want to upgrade if it's absolutely necessary (i.e. security issues).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Movable Type 4.38 has a [patch for a security vulnerability](http://www.movabletype.org/2013/01/movable_type_438_patch.html) which you should be sure to apply.  But beyond that, you should absolutely upgrade to Movable Type 5.2.3.

The big reason is that Movable Type 4.38 will be end-of-lifed on December 31, 2013.  This means that there will be no security updates for Movable Type 4.38 after that date.

[Movable Type 5](http://movabletype.com/) has a number of great new features that are huge improvements over MT 4.38:

- New and improved Rich Text Editor based on TinyMCE
- Revision history on the most-used objects in the CMS
- List-management framework enhances Movable Type's ability to manage large amounts of data inside the CMS
- Sortable categories and folders
- Template tags for things like mt:EntryPrimaryCategory
- Enhanced multi-blog support
- Huge support improvements for Webkit-based browsers (Safari and Google Chrome) as well as IE 8 and 9
- Login failure detection, allowing either account or IP address lock out

With all due respect, no one should be running a version of Movable Type that is no longer supported with security patches.  It's foolish to think that any one person can know all of the possible security issues in an older version of a Content Management System such as Movable Type.

Comment: Thanks. I just upgraded, and except for a few minor issues, it went quite smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MT4 is no longer developed. It still receive security patchs every few months, but there will not be a new version.

As for what you want to use, MT4 and MT5 have a different set of plugins. So if you want to upgrade, check that the plugins that you need support MT5 or have a MT5 replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading would work without any problem if you are not using 3rd party plugins.

If you're using 3rd party plugins, you might encounter compatibility issues because the v5.x architecture is much different than 4.x.

Before considering to upgrade to v5.x you may like to check your 3rd party plugins and see if there is a version that works with v5.x.

Another thing to consider is to clone your installation and try to upgrade it on a different domain/folder or on a stage server where you could check that everything works before upgrading your live installation.

Alternatively you could order a professional movable type upgrade service from:
http://www.movabletypeupgrade.com/

Comment: You may want to consider the passage in the FAQ that says "the community frowns on overt self-promotion" http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion